# are there limitations on .pyc files?

Tags: python-2.7

I was recently trying to make my own module when I realised a copy of my module had been made but instead of ending in .py like the origional, it ended in .pyc. When I opened it, I could not understand a thing. I was using the import to make a game from pygame and the fact that the .pyc file had a bunch of question marks and weird symbols seemed to be helpful for hackers if I ever make a game good enough for release which probably wont happen. I just want to know a few things about these files:

- Can other computers that download the game still read the module if I delete the original and only leave the weirder .pyc file?
- Are they readable by humans and can they actually prevent hacks on downloaded game? (its not online I just don't want a easy game for people who know python)
- Should I get rid of them for what I am doing? (I saw other questions asking how to do that but the answers said it was helpful)
- Last but not least, will it work for .txt files (will they not just be read as a bunch of symbols)?

Thanks!

Comment: "... will it work for .txt files ... " will what work?

Answer (score 0):

The .pyc files are not readable by humans - the python interpreter compiles the source code to these files, and they are used by the python virtual machine. You can delete these files, and when you run the .py file again, you will see a new .pyc file created.